# How to reuse drivers downloaded through Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update, smartcard

I'm looking for a way to isolate a smart card driver that is downloaded through Windows Update when I put it the first time on an RFID reader. 
The idea is then to install that driver on multiple Windows 7 computers where Windows Update is disabled. Ideally, I'd like this driver to be detected automatically on the machines.

How do I do that?

More info:

- Putting the card on the reader on Win 7 machines with Windows Update disabled shows a "Drivers not found" error popup.
- The driver doesn't seem to be available as a stand alone download on the Windows Update Catalogue, or is too hard to find.
- The driver isn't available from the smart card manufacturers website.
- The reader driver is not the issue - it's installed and works on all machines.
- The workaround suggested on the [technet kb article 976854](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976854) for this issue is not applicable to my situation: group policy modifications to disable smart card PnP is prohibited in my environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`
2. Look for a `.cab` file containing either some name or string that matches your smart card, or a `KB######` string (the text "kb" or "KB" followed by 6 numbers).
3. If you found a KB number, plug it into this URL: `http://microsoft.com/kb/######` in place of the `#` characters.
4. Read the KB article; if it talks about your device, you've found your driver.
5. Use `cabextract` or a similar program (`7-Zip` may work as well) to extract the contents of the desired .cab file.
6. You'll probably have an `.inf` file as well as various others: maybe a `.dll`, maybe a `.sys`, maybe `.vxd`, maybe `.exe`. The actual method to install the driver will vary, but one sure-fire way of doing it is going into the Device Manager, right click on the problem device (it'll show up as some kind of generic smart card or an "Unknown Device", or have an exclamation point next to it), go to Properties, then Update Driver, then pick the folder where you extracted the CAB file to. It should find your INF file and figure out how to install the driver from there.

If you can't find your update in the supplied folder, there are other, less elegant ways to do this...

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` search for the device name and you sould find a a download link to the driver. Download the CAB, extract it and use it the next time to update the driver with the [help of Device Manager](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html).